# Android layout help aligning complex blocks

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to display

```
____txt1txt1txt1____img1

____txt2____________img1
```

or

```
____txt1____________img1

____txt2txt2txt2____img1
```

depending on which text takes the most horizontal space.

img1 is the same in both lines. I fix the image on the right, and then center the TextView in the remaining space. However I would like txt1 and txt2 to be aligned, as in the example.

I have found the property `layout_alignLeft` but I don't know how to use it in this case.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What have you actually tried? Post your layout XML

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TextView` where you set an image to the right:

for Java Code:
`yourTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, img1);`

or XML:
`android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img1"`

Then set a padding:
`android:paddingLeft="5dp"`

Comment: Can you add multiple images like that ?